# Resolvent definition: bounded operator vs. unbounded operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, continuity

Maybe my question is obvious in some sense, but I ask here because I didn’t find a “satisfactory” answer on the web.

If we have a bounded or unbounded operator, the definition of resolvent changes? And, in general, why one should prefer to work with a bounded operator instead of an unbounded one?

Also some references will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't significant difference.

Let $V$ be a Banach space, and $T:V\rightarrow V$ be unbounded, closed, and densely-defined with domain $D(T)$. The resolvent set $\rho (T)$ is the collection of all $\zeta\in \mathbb{C}$ for which $\zeta-T:D(T)\rightarrow V$ is bijective. The resolvent is the operator $R_\zeta:=(\zeta-T)^{-1}:V\rightarrow D(T)$, which is defined for $\zeta\in\rho(T).$ Just like in the case of $T$ bounded, the resolvent is a bounded operator, by the closed-graph theorem.

One should note that this requires an appropriate choice of domain, and the resolvent set (and spectrum) can look quite a bit different for unbounded operators.

To answer your second question, bounded operators are easier to work with. Unbounded operators lead to more technicalities, much of which is a byproduct of needing to make a "nice" choice of domain.

For a reference, see the functional analysis appendix of Michael Taylor's *Partial Differential Equations I: Basic Theory*.